# jQuery condition not matching

Tags: c#, jquery, html, asp.net

I have the following HTML

```html
<div id='cssmenu'>
  <ul>
    <li class= 'has-sub'>
      <a href=store.aspx?id=dLYTWvt8EsHOq7Ps2wJA9A%3d%3d&digest=tNy7s/jOrynR4pvMVN6d6Q==><span>Armed Combat</span></a>
      <ul>
        <li class= 'has-sub'>
          <a href=store.aspx?id=xEDEzZWDRkX8%2fbXoMX2pSQ%3d%3d&digest=tNy7s/jOrynR4pvMVN6d6Q==><span>Armed Combat 1-2</span></a>
          <ul>
            <li class= 'active'><a href=store.aspx?id=TxlSRrnSZ6HDgj%2b2ZSxRhg%3d%3d&digest=tNy7s/jOrynR4pvMVN6d6Q==><span>Dance -1</span></a></li>
            <li class= 'active'><a href=store.aspx?id=Y7JxNAXSuG1T%2f0cpjQXSwA%3d%3d&digest=tNy7s/jOrynR4pvMVN6d6Q==><span>Dance - 2</span></a></li>
            <li class= 'active'><a href=store.aspx?id=%2fcoJMcJTjWp3%2bPuimR5AhA%3d%3d&digest=tNy7s/jOrynR4pvMVN6d6Q==><span>Armed Combat 1-5</span></a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class= 'has-sub'>
          <a href=store.aspx?id=KC2g4igBzXisbsbKu%2fKrzw%3d%3d&digest=tNy7s/jOrynR4pvMVN6d6Q==><span>Armed Combat 1-3</span></a>
          <ul>
            <li class= 'active'><a href=store.aspx?id=8DCHnP%2b4KQVYDTGxVt9snQ%3d%3d&digest=tNy7s/jOrynR4pvMVN6d6Q==><span>Death -1</span></a></li>
            <li class= 'active'><a href=store.aspx?id=nGEm4rbNMQ%2bQfyO44ECmpA%3d%3d&digest=tNy7s/jOrynR4pvMVN6d6Q==><span>Death - 1</span></a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class= 'has-sub'><a href=store.aspx?id=feki%2bXDs66obnO1e2dxHWg%3d%3d&digest=tNy7s/jOrynR4pvMVN6d6Q==><span>Armed Combat 1-4</span></a></li>
        <li class= 'has-sub'><a href=store.aspx?id=5O394Lww9oxD1vHbIY7LWw%3d%3d&digest=tNy7s/jOrynR4pvMVN6d6Q==><span>Armed Combat 1-6</span></a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class= 'active'><a href=store.aspx?id=RIe63RBggHzj76SUwDHKMg%3d%3d&digest=tNy7s/jOrynR4pvMVN6d6Q==><span>Dance</span></a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

And in `reqid`

```js
var reqid = "<%=Request["id"]%>";
```

In `reqid` I will get urlencoded based on menu selection

My jQuery code here

```js
$(function () {
    var str = $("#cssmenu").find('li').find('a').attr('href');

    if ($(str).has(reqid)) {    
        var str2 = $("#cssmenu").find('li').find('a').text();
        $('#selectedmenuitem').html(str2);
    }
});
```

If the `href` attribute encoded url contains selected menu item encodedurl i want to get the matched url `.text()` to the `#selectedmenuitem` label id.

I checked with contains, am not getting. Please suggest me what are other possibilities for this.

Comment: This is not the exact problem .If str contains reqid .encoded url contains half of selected menu encoded url .how to specify the condition ...contains ans has is not working

Comment: can you provide sample html?

Comment: I pasted my HTML but it is not showing

Comment: I think `<%=Request["id"]%>` should be `<%=Request.QueryString["id"]%>`

Answer (score 0):

use indexOf function of Javascript

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp

Comment: href contains half of reqid encodedurl .If both are same i can use ur code but reqid is part of href.

Answer (score 0):

Use following jquery code

```
$(function () {
    var str2= $("#cssmenu").find("li").find("a[href*='" + reqid + "']").text();
    $('#selectedmenuitem').html(str2);
});
```